# Connected components of the isotropic Grassmannian

Tags: complex-manifolds

Let $W$ be a $2n$-dimensional complex vector space endowed with a non-degenerate, symmetric, bilinear form $Q$.  We choose  Euclidean coordinates on  $W$ such that  $Q$ is represented by  symmetric matrix \begin{align*}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & I_n \\
I_n & 0
\end{array}\right],
\end{align*}
where $I_n$ the  identity matrix of order $n$. Define $\operatorname{Gr}_{Q}(n,2n)$ to be the
Grassmannian of isotropic  $n$-planes in $W$( for any $n$-plane $V$, we have $Q|_V=0$). I'm having some trouble understanding how the isotropic  Grassmannian
$\operatorname{Gr}_{Q}(n,2n)$ has two
irreducible
connected components. Any information would be helpful!